# Change get_current_user_id code to the author's profile

Tags: plugins, php, author

I've been modifying a long abandoned plugin project that provides a Stackoverflow inspired badge system for Wordpress. I have upgraded some of its code so it functions with the new Wordpress version.

You can view the entire code here if you are interested: http://pastebin.com/kCWWLPL2

I want to add a code to the author.php page to list the author's awarded badges. So far, I have only managed to display the logged in user's badges with this working code:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id != 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $user_id));
}
?>
```

I was told to use this code to display the author's badges:

```
<?php
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ); 
if ($author->ID > 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $author->ID));
}
?>
```

But it does not return anything on the page. Why? What am I doing wrong here? How can I alter the working get_current_user_id code example so that it will **display the author's badges and not the logged in user's one**?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `get_current_user_id()` use

```
$current_view = get_queried_object();
```

The `$current_view` will have the same properties as `get_current_user()` if it is used in author.php. To get the User ID, just use

```
$current_view_id = $current_view->ID
```

Hope this help